# Avoid lexicographic ordering of numerical values with Python min() max()

Tags: python, sorting, max, min

I have a script to pull random numbers from a set of values. However, it broke today because `min()` and `max()` sort values by lexicographic order (so 200 is considered greater than 10000). How can I avoid lexicographic order here? `Len` key is on the right track but not quite right. I couldn't find any other key(s) that would help.

```
data_set = 1600.csv, 2405.csv, 6800.csv, 10000.csv, 21005.csv
```

First try:

```
highest_value = os.path.splitext(max(data_set))[0]
lowest_value = os.path.splitext(min(data_set))[0]
```

returns: `lowest_value = 10000` `highest_value = 6800`

Second try:

```
highest_value = os.path.splitext(max(data_set,key=len))[0]
lowest_value = os.path.splitext(min(data_set,key=len))[0]
```

returns: `lowest_value = 1600` `highest_value = 10000`

Thanks.

Comment: did you try `key=int`?

Comment: Using just `int` like that would raise a `ValueError`, @Paul. Of course, I'm assuming that his data set elements are strings.

Comment: @ChristianDean my dataset is essentially a `dir` of numerically named files in a folder, hence the `splitext`.. does that help?

Comment: @chrissmit.yam90 I think I understand what you want. Check my answer below to see if I'm right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `key` to order by the numeric part of the file:

```
data_set = ['1600.csv', '2405.csv', '6800.csv', '10000.csv', '21005.csv']

highest = max(data_set, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
lowest = min(data_set, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))

print(highest) # >> 21005.csv
print(lowest)  # >> 1600.csv
```

Comment: thank you.. what i understand is that lambda splits the extension, converts to int, and then max/min sorts it.. correct? i have never used lambda

Comment: Yes, "lambda" is just a function written differently. In this case, the lambda function splits the name of the file into the number part and the 'csv' part, and converts the number part into an int. The max/min function uses that int part to decide which is the max/min. You could also write a "normal" function to do this instead of using a lambda expression. It looks like the other answer from christian-dean did it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You were close. Rather than using the result of `splittext` with the `len` function, use the `int` function instead:

```
>>> from os.path import splitext
>>> data_set = ['1600.csv', '2405.csv', '6800.csv', '10000.csv', '21005.csv']
>>> def convert_to_int(file_name):
        return int(splitext(file_name)[0])

>>> min(data_set, key=convert_to_int)
'1600.csv'
>>> max(data_set, key=convert_to_int)
'21005.csv'
```

Of course, this solution assumes that your file name will consist solely of numerical values.

Comment: This worked, but it doesn't fit my situation as well as Leopold's answer. Still, thank you.